# Pinch-To-Zoom feature for TiledScrollView

Tags: android, scroll, catiledlayer, pinchzoom, deepzoom

I used https://github.com/ened/Android-Tiling-ScrollView library to display large tiled image. Everything is working fine. Only problem is that, I want to zoom only particular part which I touched(pinch-to-zoom as in Google map). Now, its always display tiles from beginning for all zoom levels irrespective of where I touched. Sometimes, it takes me near where I want to zoom but its not perfect as sometimes it takes me to different part. Following code does moving logic

```
mScroller.startScroll(getScrollX(), getScrollY(), newOffsetX, newOffsetY);
```

First 2 parameters indicate start scroll offset and last 2 indicates destination points to where scroll ends. I tried different combinations for last 2 parameters but ran out of luck.

If it's a `ImageView`, I would have done

```
canvas.translate(x, y);
```

to Zoom particular part but unfortunately its not `ImageView`. Even though I applied `ImageView` zoom logic as in https://github.com/jasonpolites/gesture-imageview to tile Zoom but had no luck.

Suggestions or clues are greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: my 50 reputation is gng waste :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got a very nice library for custom mapView with almost all the features of google map. Its [here](https://github.com/moagrius/TileView).